# Redshift boto3 describe_clusters via prefix

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, boto3

I'm trying to use the boto3 describe_clusters function to get a list of all the redshift clusters on our account by using a prefix and not the full name.

Let's say I have 2 redshift clusters called **my-cluster-one **and **my-cluster-two**. I want to be able to view all cluster's starting with that prefix like below for example.

```
response = redshift_client.describe_clusters(
        ClusterIdentifier='my-cluster-*'
    )
```

When I do run the above code I get the follwing error.
*"An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the DescribeClusters operation: The parameter DBInstanceIdentifier is not a valid identifier. Identifiers must begin with a letter; must contain only ASCII letters, digits, and hyphens; and must not end with a hyphen or contain two consecutive hyphens."*

```
response = redshift_client.describe_clusters(
        ClusterIdentifier='my-cluster'
    )
```

When I try to solve the above mentioned error by removing the '-*' characters from the name. It still cant use the prefix and requires a full name.
*"An error occurred (ClusterNotFound) when calling the DescribeClusters operation: Cluster my-cluster not found."*

So it does not seem possible using a prefix/a section of the name like I tried. The code does work perfectly fine with a full name like my-cluster-one (Just to confirm everything else is in fact working).

Does anyone know of a work around that would enable me to use a prefix?
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you confirm that this cluster exists.

Comment: The describe_clusters call can return all clusters if you do not filter for the ClusterIdentifier. You can then filter client-side for the relevant clusters.

Comment: Thanks! @MP24 Removing the filter for the ClusterIdentifier worked liked you said. This was my first example with a boto3 function where I don't specify any parameters hence I did not think it was possible. 

Thanks for the quick help!

Answer (score 0):

The `describe_clusters` call can return all clusters if you do not filter for the `ClusterIdentifier`. You can then filter client-side for the relevant clusters.

See https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/redshift/client/describe_clusters.html - there is no mandatory parameter.